# Sync only on screen on

Tags: sync, 4.1-jelly-bean, notifications, nexus-4, push-notifications

I just bought a Nexus 4 (4.2.2), the problem is thta whatsapp/gmail/facebook (all apps) only show notifications when the screen is turned off (so I'm not notified if a message arrives with a led, sound nor vibration) until I actually check my phone.

I have deactivated the wifi baterry saving option, set the wifi to always on (instead of off during sleep), and nothing :S

I had a motorola razr and this problem never happened to me.

Comment: if i get your question you want to know how to stop notification when screen is off ?

Comment: The opposite actually, I have been looking into XDA and some other forums and it turns out that the Wifi driver has a bug in the Nexus 4 which delays notifications uo to 30 minutes! Thanks though :)